# One soon gave out his last breath

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from the book "*The Wager*" by David Grann. It's the beginning of the book in which a group of emanciated survivors found onboard a small drifting boat is described:

*"Some were so weak they could not even stand. One soon gave out his last
breath and died."*

I know what "gave out one's breath" mean. It means to die. But I don't quite understand what "give out" mean in this context. I looked up "give out" in couple of dictionaries and one definition that is being repeated is:

(tr) to emit or discharge.

The problem with this defnition is that I didn't really know if **emit** could be used with **breath**.
I know you can emit a sound but can you emit a breath? Does "*give out one's last breath*" mean to "emit one's last breath" (essentially produce one's last breath)?

Comment: We *tend* to use ***emit*** more today for things like electromagnetic waves (obviously unknown when that word first entered the English language), but it's fine for breathing out one's last gasp.

Comment: Or you could substitute **exhaled** or even **took** for **gave out**.

Comment: To my (American) ear, both "give out breath" and "emit breath" are unusual, but not impossible. We usually emit liquid, light, heat, or sound. Gas is sometimes emitted (e.g., from Wikipedia, "Exhaust gas [...] is emitted as a result of the combustion of fuels such as natural gas, gasoline..."), so breath in particular is not a huge stretch.

Comment: @George K Yeah, I hear alot about emitting too many greenhouse gases but this poses another question whether a human gas (fart) can be said to be "emited". I would say the stretch is even smaller here. It's not a joke (even though it's funny), I really wonder if you can use "emit" for such a thing :D I guess I'm more hungry for knowledge than trying to be polite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Emit* is possible.

If you are looking for words or phrases to describe such a scene, you may consider **breathed his last**.

> ... One soon breathed his last (and died).

[Breathe one's last](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breathe%20one%27s%20last) is an idiom.

> literary
> : to die
> This is the room where he breathed his last.

Ngram shows this idiom to be [much more common than the use of expressions involving **emit**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=emit_INF+his+last+breath%2Cexhale_INF+his+last+breath%2Cbreathe_INF+his+last&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). I added expressions using **exhale** for comparison.